# Sugerencias para hacer web scraping

Tags: python, web, csv

Hola mundo de stack overflow.

Lo que sucede monitoreo unos paneles solares mediante una página web que trabaja en conjunto con el hardware de los monitores. Lo que necesito realizar es ver la manera de loguear con cada uno de los usuarios (mis clientes) para no estar ingresando yo manualmente c/u de ellos.

Una vez iniciando sesión necesito aplicar el crawling para extraes sus datos y generar mis reportes. De momento conozco python con su libreria scrapy más no se si pudieran recomendarme algún otro lenguaje y/o herramienta con el que pudiera realizar lo anteriormente mencionado de una manera más sencilla y rápida.

Comment: Estaría bueno que expliques mejor lo que queres hacer. Lo que se entiende es que queres autenticarte en un sitio y scrapear una página. Si queres saber librerías de raspado en general aparte de scrapy tenes beautiful soup y lxml. Combinando esto con expresiones regulares suele bastar pero si por ejemplo el contenido se carga con ajax o por websockets ya es otra historia

Comment: Como bien te dice @lopezezequiel tendríamos que saber si el contenido que te interesa está integrado en la estructura HTML de la página **en el momento de cargarse** , o por el contrario aparece después, una vez que se ejectuan determinadas acciones (darle a un botón, escribir texto dentro de un campo...). Esto lo puedes comprobar tú mismo: (1) Deshabilitando Javascript en tu navegador, (2) En las herramientas de Desarrollo de tu navegador, dentro de la pestaña 'Red' (donde puedes revisar qué partes de la página se cargan primero y cuáles después).